# Ver datos de variables en punto de interrupcion visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, variables, visual-studio-2017, depuración

Vengo con una pequeña duda que no se si es debido a un cambio en el aplicativo del visual studio  2017 o alguna otra configuración adicional que tengo que hacer, anteriormente en el vs2010 cuando colocaba un punto de interrupción para verificar que datos se iban cargados en las variables me visualizaba el valor cuando ponía el cursor, por ejemplo sobre la variable fi me mostraba la fecha 21-09-20, pero ahora por mas que coloque el cursor no me visualiza ningún valor, alguien me podría orientar para saber que debo hacer para volver a ver esos valores?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hasta lo que yo se no tienes que configurar nada, siempre me anduvo bien, probaste reiniciar el visual? me suele pasar que por un momento no me carga el dato o se demora.

Comment: Entra aquí http://wintablet.info/2015/09/no-se-inspeccionan-bien-las-variables-en-el-depurador-de-visual-studio-2015-solucion/

Comment: Estuve buscando  y logre encontrar la solución gracias a este link https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/2148344